# jQuery tabs and CSS

Tags: jquery-ui

I am trying to use jQuery tabs with cookies. I got it working but the CSS to style the tabs isn't working and I need some help to get it working. I downloaded jQuery and extratced it into a folder called **development-bundle**

Here is my link to the css but it's not working.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Sticky Tab</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="development-bundle/externals/css/jquery-ui/ui-lightness/1.7.2/jquery-ui-lightness.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
            <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="development-bundle/externals/jquery/core/1.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="development-bundle/externals/jquery/ui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="development-bundle/cookies/jquery.cookies.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( function()
        {
            var cookieName, $tabs, stickyTab;

            cookieName = 'stickyTab';
            $tabs = $( '#tabs' );

            $tabs.tabs( {
                select: function( e, ui )
                {
                    $.cookies.set( cookieName, ui.index );
                }
            } );

            stickyTab = $.cookies.get( cookieName );
            if( ! isNaN( stickyTab )  )
            {
                $tabs.tabs( 'select', stickyTab );
            }
        } );
    </script>
</body>
```

This is what am getting[image]

But this is what am trying to achieve
[image]

Any suggestions on what am doing wrong here with my css link ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adding CSS classes to your markup.

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

See the source for this example. Make sure your browser isn't reporting any errors.

Comment: Thanks I got it working now. But another issue is am trying to use the tabs in php.When I change the extension from html to php then the css and the tabs doesn't work again. Do you have any idea why that's the case or does it not work with php and only meant to work with html?